# VS Code automatic indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation, auto-indent

I have a problem with automatic indentation in VS Code. If you pay attention to the gif below, you will see that the editor only moves a tab forward for the first time, but the second time it should automatically detect that a tab moves forward, but this is not the case. Many editors do not have this problem, but it has really become a problem for me. Also, for example, I do not want to press a shortcut key to solve this problem, I expect the editor to handle.

[image]

Comment: put the cursor after the `{` and press enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Just disable `trimAutoWhitespace` in VS Code settings.